# Echobot doesn't work on Line(doesn't response message)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning how to develop a LineBot and I start with create an EchoBot
(I used to try to develop MessengerBot before, but I changed my mind due to Messenger's certification)

I saw documents and ran with these[codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY061.png)

```js
var linebot = require('linebot');


var bot = linebot({
    channelId: '1654066411',
    channelSecret: 'f8283d4b9d43b184433f34ee56b4340c',
    channelAccessToken: '9c07bc6f-d7e9-4570-9da3-b67a60672720'
});


bot.on('message', function (event) {

    var replyMsg = `Hello你剛才說的是:${event.message.text}`;

    event.reply(replyMsg).then(function (data) {

        console.log(replyMsg);
    }).catch(function (error) {

        console.log("fail");
    });
});


bot.listen('/linewebhook', 3000, function () {
    console.log('[BOT已準備就緒]');
});
```

and used ngrok so my teammates could test it. Though these codes get what messages we sent and show in terminal(and ngrok also response 200 OK), there is nothing show on Line chatroom.

I wonder if there is any problem in my code, or there is another setting should I check?

I'm sorry this is my first time ask a question on this website, if there is any content I need to add please tell me, thanks.

Comment: `I wonder if there is any problem in my code` please post it

Comment: @Nelles I pasted my code in a link first, now I show them in the article. Is that ok for you to see what mistake in my code?